# Create/update file(s) post dependency install, with Yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, writefile, post-install

I would like to create/update file(s) after the dependencies have been installed, when the generator(`generator-custom`) has been executed.

`$ yo custom`

Any pointer would be very helpful.

---

For example, I am trying to update the `devDependencies` section of the  `package.json` with respect to the dependent packages `devDependencies` after the dependencies have been installed. However I am unable to achieve it. Please find the below code snippet.

```
install: function () {
  this.installDependencies({
    skipInstall: this.options['skip-install'],
    callback: function () {
      var pkgPath = process.cwd() + '/package.json';
      var pkg = require(pkgPath);
      pkg.devDependencies = {
        "grunt": "~0.4.2"
      };
      this.write(pkgPath, JSON.stringify(pkg));
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
```

The idea behind updating the package.json, was to rerun the installDependencies function. So that when ever the core package updates its dependency, the generator does not require to update its template.

As suggested by @SimonBoudrias, the above is not efficient way to perform the operation. The dependent packages can be installed by using peerDependencies of the main dependent package.

---

Comment: Why do you want to add devDependencies after the installation ran? This'll just confuse the hell out of your users.

Comment: Actually, I want to copy the devDependencies from the package.json of one of the dependent package and rerun the install.

Comment: The reason behind, is that I can avoid updating the generator when the main dependency's dependency changes. Please suggest if there are any better way to do so.

Comment: Use composability then. No need to wait for a composed generator installation to run, and you'll be able to write the same files without actually hitting the hard drive. http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html and http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html

Comment: Thanks @SimonBoudrias. I guess I can achieve the same with peerDependencies of the main dependent package.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias could you suggest me how to perform write/update file operation after dependency installation?

Comment: My point is, Yeoman is not expecting you to write after the installation phase. So most way you'll try won't work. There's no reason you should need the installation to run before hand. By fetching the `package.json`, you'll have all the information you need to write any files.

Answer (score 0):

> > I would like to create/update file(s) after the dependencies have been installed, when the generator(generator-custom) has been executed.

The following snippet serves the desired use case.

```
this.npmInstall(['npm-module'], {}, function() {
  this.write('path/to/file', 'file-content');
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Yes, but no. That won't work with the latest versions of `yeoman-generator`.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. We fixed the code on our end to make such patterns work. Still, I believe this is a flawed logic you should handle differently.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias is the use case is flawed or the implementation? Could you please suggest a better approach?